# Out of memory exception when using a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I need to collect Dictionary using NET Framework 2.0. I am not an expert in this language. Dictionary must contain a special information about every day. 
I simplified the example and create it without IDE, sorry if I have inaccuracies.

```
Dictionary<string, int> copy = new Dictionary<string,int>();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dayResult = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

//initialization
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    copy.Add(i.ToString(),0);
}
for(int day = 0; day < 3000; day++) {
    dayResult.Add(day.ToString(), copy);
}

for(int k = 0; k < 1000; k++){
    for(int day = 0; day < 3000; day++) {
        copy = new Dictionary<string, int>(dayResult[day.ToString()]);
        copy[randomValue.ToString()]++;
        dayResult[day.ToString()] = copy; 
    }
}
```

I get an out of memory exception. But if I changed the  line

```
copy = new Dictionary(dayResult[day.ToString()]);
```

to

```
copy = dayResult[day.ToString()];
```

I get the same result for everyday, but my randomValue changes every time from 0 to 9 that is why it's impossible.

**Read carefully**

I am trying to collect the data for everyday. This data has a lot of keys and the keys have different frequencies. I need to understand which set of keys met with a specific frequency on a particular day. What am I doing wrong?

**PS**

I am work in special IDE and I can't control "for" cycles:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
    for(int day = 0; day < 3000; day++)
```

that is why I can only save and initialize data.

Comment: You have a loop with 3 million iterations and in each one you make a new dictionary with a high starting capacity, so that's probably something to do with it. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: To clarify: Are you stating that you're using version 2.0 of the C# language (which was provided by .NET Framework 2.0), or do you mean that you're using .NET Core 2.0 (which currently supports up to C# 7.X)?

Comment: What ever you are doing, there is a 99.99345345% chance you are taking the wrong approach. Can you explain what you want to acheive?

Comment: NET Framework 2.0. I am trying to collect the data for every day. This data has a lot of keys and the keys have different frequencies. I need to understand which set of keys met with a specific frequency on a particular day

Comment: You need to write `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of the file @Kotlindummy. That won't fix the `copy = new Dictionary(dayResult[day.ToString()]);` line though - since that code is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to get a nested dictionary :

```
            List<int> firstList = (new string('\0', 100)).Select((x,i) => i).ToList();
            List<int> secondList = (new string('\0', 1000)).Select((x, i) => i).ToList();
            Random rand = new Random();
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dayResult = secondList
                .GroupBy(x => x.ToString(), y => firstList
                    .GroupBy(a => a.ToString(), b => rand.Next())
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But there is no linq in NET Framework 2.0. And I can't add addition libraries.